# Code First Entity Framework not building database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to implement Entity Framework using code first but it is not building the database tables. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. I am using this tutorial -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542 but I am trying to use it with a web application instead of a console application. I created a Models folder and put my context class in that folder. Here is my dbcontext code:

```
namespace GroceryAssistant.Model
{
    public class GroceryShopperContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<List> Lists { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ListItem> ListItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I created put the connection string in the web.release.config and the web.debug.config files. I'm not sure what else I have to do. Where should i put my DbContext code so that the tables will be created?

Comment: Do you ever instantiate that context?

Comment: Where should I do this in a web application?

Comment: You should create it, use it and quickly release it as often as you need it. For example in a MVC app you can create a context in a controller action, select the items to show on the page and release it.

Comment: Ok, so does this mean that first time I use it, it will create the tables. Then from then on it will see the tables exist?

Comment: Yes, so if you get to item 4 in your tutorial you should have the db created.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not change the default behavior, the first time you use the DbContext it will create your database.

Comment: I added code to the Page_Load method of my master page, just to get the database created, but it just threw an error. The application is looking in the App_Data folder for the database. Do you know what this means?

Comment: what database are you trying to use? if you have sql express installed and you remove the connection string from the web.config it will create the db in the sql express which is a pretty good way to get started...

Comment: I commented out the references to the sql express db in the web.config files and i'm getting the same error.